# trying to save a turtlebot map with android

Tags: turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am having issues with the two android_make_a_map.launch and android_map_nav.launch

When trying to save the map from make_a_map.launch I get the following error on my android.

**"naming map couldn't even start: no such service save_map of type map_store/savemap"**

When I try to run android_map_nav.launch it fails and hangs on trying to open. app launch failed.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12980/trying-to-save-a-turtlebot-map-with-android/) by [retloc](https://answers.ros.org/users/1226/retloc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-02-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

try to install map_store package, it worked for me on ros electric

---

Originally posted by [SHPOWER](https://answers.ros.org/users/2209/shpower/) with karma: 302 on 2012-09-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1